# Nested cell arrays

Tags: java

I would like to implement nested cell arrays (Matlab) in java. Since i am new to java programming i am not sure what could be used in java similar to nested cell arrays.

Basically, like shown in table below in each cell i would like to have an array of elements within which i want to place a value say 0 or 1 and the next element of an array should be an array.

[image]

Could you please suggest how to implement this in java? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it seems you want a list of your own defined data structure. I would say create a class which defines your structure and create a list of that class.

Say the class Ele

**Ele**

```
    public class Ele{
      public Ele(){
        array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      }
      // To define your 0 or 1
      public int element;

      // To store your array
      public List<Integer> array;
    }
```

Now for Input you can do:

```
    List<Ele> elements = new ArrayList<Ele>();

    // Input 
    Ele singleElement = new Ele();
    singleElement.element = 1;
    singleElement.array.add(1);
    singleElement.array.add(2);
    singleElement.array.add(3);
    elements.add(singleElement);
```

For output:

```
    // Output
    for(Ele ele : elements){
        System.out.println("Element = " + ele.element);
        System.out.println("Array = " + ele.array);
    }
```

**Console Output is**

Element = 1
Array = [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

Implement a class that represents a cell of this nested cell array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class NestedCell<T> {

    private int element;
    private List<T> nestedCellArray;

    public NestedCell(int element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.nestedCellArray = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void addItem(T item) {
        nestedCellArray.add(item);
    }

    // your methods come here, getters, setters, etc



}
```

To declare and operate with one-dimensional nested-cells array, that uses `Integer`/`int` values in `array` element of `NestedCell` class you can use the following code:

```
List<NestedCell<Integer>> nestedCellsArray = new ArrayList<>();

// declaring and populating cell #1
NestedCell nestedCell1 = new NestedCell(123);
nestedCell1.addItem(-134);
nestedCell1.addItem(32);
nestedCell1.addItem(716);

// declaring and populating cell #2
NestedCell nestedCell2 = new NestedCell(456);
nestedCell2.addItem(-8);
nestedCell2.addItem(2);
nestedCell2.addItem(3);
nestedCell2.addItem(44);
nestedCell2.addItem(991);

// adding cells to the array
nestedCellsArray.add(nestedCell1);
nestedCellsArray.add(nestedCell2);
```

If you want to use another type for `nestedCellArray` field, instead of`Integer` (let say `Double`), use this declaration:

```
List<NestedCell<Double>> nestedCellsArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can make two-dimensional nested cell arrays by declaring a list of one-dimensional nested cell arrays and so on, to make multi-dimensional nested cell arrays.